# activeandroid orm library index=true and unique=true not working

Tags: java, android, activeandroid

As activeandroid library suggests to use annotation unique and index annotation parameters here,

```
@Column(name = "Category", index = true)
public String category;
```

I tried to implement this but the annotation parameters index or unique are not available in the library. I am using version 3.0 jar Tried version3.1 beta also,same issue there. While 3.1 is the latest jar available, am I missing something? Please suggest a solution to create indexes when using activeandroid library. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, solved the problem by updating to version 3.1.0
remember to add the dependency like this:

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: Thanks @Firass, There are lots of issues pending in activeandroid repo so upgrading through maven repo may delay development if any issue occurs. Can you guide me how to import v3.1.0 using source code, so at least I can fix up issues by debugging.  I will try your solution also but I have tried v3.1.0 using jar and same issue occured there also.